# Android RecyclerView inside popupwindow is not working?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, popupwindow

## popup_layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
 android:id="@+id/cardView"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:elevation="2dp"
 app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/landmarkView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/btn_take_photo_surrounding"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Above code is design for How `PopUpWindow` will look like. I am opening this `PopWindows` on `EditText.addTextChangedListener.onTextChanged()` by calling following method:

```
 private void popupWindow() {
    int popupwindowHeight = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(
            R.layout.dashboard_profile_popup_window, null);

    final PopupWindow pwindow = new PopupWindow(layout, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    pwindow.setHeight(popupwindowHeight);
    pwindow.setFocusable(true);
    pwindow.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
            //TODO dismiss settings
        }
    });
    RecyclerView landmarkRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.landmarkView);
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    data.add("my data");
    data.add("set Data");

    landmarkRecyclerView.setAdapter(new LandmarkRecyclerViewAdapter(data, getContext()));
   
    pwindow.setWindowLayoutMode(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    pwindow.setHeight(1);
    pwindow.setWidth(1);
    pwindow.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, mPoint.x, mPoint.y);
    pwindow.showAsDropDown(place_pop_up);
}
```

But what I can see through above code is :
[image]

A blank `PopUpWindow` on Text change listener. What I am doing wrong here?

## edit

Adding `LandMarkRecyclerViewAdapter` too

```
public class LandmarkRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LandmarkRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<String> mLocalityEntities;

public LandmarkRecyclerViewAdapter(List<String> localityEntityList, Context context){
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mLocalityEntities = localityEntityList;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.landmark_view_adapter, null);
    ViewHolder  holder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if( null != mLocalityEntities.get(position)){
        holder.mTextView.setText(mLocalityEntities.get(position).toString());
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mLocalityEntities.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView mTextView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.landmarkText);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: As in posted xml only `landmarkView ` `RecyclerView ` is avalaible where is next?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I have removed the now.

Comment: Amit , Probably issue is related to height's of Views,so try it after using some static height for PopWindow like change `int popupwindowHeight = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;` to `int popupwindowHeight =250` and also `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to android:layout_height="match_parent" for `RecyclerView `

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I tried got no effect.

Comment: Added adapter class as well